# How does the dmatrix in xgboost store data

Tags: python, c++, xgboost

i use xgboost model both in c++ and python,at first time,they give me different predicts.
after i modify the code in python, i used pandas to load data,but now,i use dmatrix to load data.then,they are same.

```py
    #data = pd.read_csv(data_path,names = features,header = None, dtype=dtypes)
    #test_x = data[features].values

    data = xgb.DMatrix(data_path)
```

How does the dmatrix in xgboost store data?

Comment: Isn't it open source? What do you already know about it, what are the questions you haven't solved yet? Also, the introductory paragraph, you write about some unexpected behaviour, is your question about that? Sorry, but I don't think you're asking a good question here and that the info you will get won't help you anyway. It might be some kind of "xy problem". As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.